# cannot send mail using phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

i have tried to use the phpmailer github example and still doesn't work
Here is the code:

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'myemailadd@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'mypassword';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('myemailadd@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('myemailadd.com', 'My name');     //Add a recipient
    // $mail->addAddress('myemailadd@gmail.com');               //Name is optional
    // $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    // $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    // $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

and the error i get is:

```
2022-02-20 08:17:00 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I am using xampp and on a proxy  server and still can't find a solutin from the github trouleshoot

Comment: Please try using a different port number 25.  Also see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137304/phpmailer-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host

Comment: @RobyRajuOommen - They can't resolve the hostname at all, so it's not a port issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your DNS is not working. This has nothing to do with PHPMailer or PHP itself, but your server, or the network it is on. Fix your DNS and it will be able to work.